# FQL statement to get a photo of two people (Query not indexable error)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE me() and $otherPerson IN ( SELECT subject FROM photo_tag WHERE pid=pid ) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```

I'm trying to get a photo that has both users tagged in it ($otherPerson is replaced with a user id). This query returns:

```
604 Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL_Tables
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

UPDATE:

I currently have this query working but I feel as though there's a better way to go about.

```
SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo
 WHERE pid IN (
                 SELECT pid FROM photo_tag 
                 WHERE subject=$otherGuy
                 AND pid in (
                                SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()
                             )
               )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT pid, src_big
FROM photo
WHERE pid IN(
    SELECT pid  
    FROM photo_tag
    WHERE subject = me()
) 
AND pid IN(
    SELECT pid  
    FROM photo_tag
    WHERE subject = <friend_user_id>
)
```

Comment: thanks christophe! this is working, however it is only fetching X amount of photos ~100 or so.  is there a way fetch ALL photos? setting "limit 99999" does not work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
  SELECT pid
    FROM photo
   WHERE me() IN (SELECT subject
                    FROM photo_tag
                   WHERE pid=pid)
     AND $otherPerson IN (SELECT subject
                            FROM photo_tag
                           WHERE pid=pid)
ORDER BY created DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Also, what `pid=pid` means?

Comment: I'm trying to select photo_tags where the pid of the `photo_tag` is equal to the pid of the `photo` but I'm not sure how to do that in FQL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other solutions and ran into a problem - If your friend has set his privacy settings to disallow apps from accessing his photos, then the following FQL query will return an empty table:

```
"SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = <friend_user_id>"
```

I solved this by using the following multiquery instead:

```
"query1" : "SELECT subject, pid FROM photo_tag WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me())"
"query2" : "SELECT pid FROM #query1 WHERE subject= <friend_user_id>"
```

Comment: Doh, I spoke to soon. The updated solution in the original question works for me as well.